Highlight first N chars (or indicate with a mark) including new lines
All the answers I found are just on a per line basis.
I want to show the first N chars in a file (say 160) including new lines.
This can be indicated by special coloring (background color) or a simple marker like for for line limits.
EDIT: with search highlight enabled, this trick works nnoremap <leader>S /\%^\_.\{274}/e<cr>.
I tried making a syntax group, but couldn't figure out how to convert char position to (line_number, column_number) in lua.
see https://medium.com/@ankochem/neovim-highlighting-the-text-programmatically-with-lua-837fecfa36d2

so use matchadd() with that pattern together with a BufWinEnter or WinEnter autocommand
